# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting the following error in Angular 4 :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined

Here's the code :

```
<form name="form"  #f="ngForm" novalidate>

  <tr>
     <td width="10%" class="text-blue"></td> 
     <td><input type="text"  name="bankname" maxlength="25" appRestrictinput ="words" [(ngModel)]="model.bk_name" #bk_name="ngModel"  class="form-control" autofocus  /> </td>
  </tr>
  <div *ngIf="bankname.invalid && (bankname.dirty || bankname.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
     <div *ngIf="bankname.errors.required">Name is required</div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Please let me know where I'm going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `bk_name`, and you are using `bankname`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your control reference in the view is `bk_name`. Replace `bankname` with `bk_name`.

```
<div *ngIf="bk_name.invalid && (bk_name.dirty || bk_name.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
<div *ngIf="bk_name.errors.required">Name is required.</div>
```

Comment: Why would underscore work, instead? is it an Ng-bootstrap keyword/property standard to follow?

Comment: He has both variables and mixed them

Answer (score 1):

You Just forgot about Template variable

Add this to your input **#bankname="ngModel"** and it will work with you

```
<input ngModel name="bankname" type="text" #bankname="ngModel" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required> <br/>

<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="bankname.invalid">bankname is required</div>
```